# Flyway maven cannot find configurations

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, flyway

I have a spring-boot project with maven used as a dependency manager. Im trying to use flyway to help in database migrations, but flyway mvn plugin is unable to find
database configurations. When I try to:

```
mvn flyway:baseline
```

It results in to error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:4.2.0:baseline (default-cli) on proj
>   ect project-name: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to connect to the database. C
>   onfigure the url, user and password! -> [Help 1]

In Flyway maven [documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/) it says that you can configure the Flyway Maven plugin through maven properties. I have set those flyway configurations in my application.properties, but that doesn't seem to help. It still can't read it from those. Have I understood what is meant by maven properties correctly? I thought they are indeed the application.properties, located in src/main/resources/. The spring-boot application is able to detect all other configs from there.

The question is: **how can I automatically configure the flyway maven plugin to use application.properties file, without specifying the property file during commands?**

Comment: are you aware that spring boot come with out-of-the-box integration for flyway? https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/springboot

Comment: Yes, I am, and was aware.The documentation for the out-of-the-box integration for flyway was so bad, that I didn't even consider using it. Only documented stuff I found was 'Execute Flyway database migrations on startup', and I need way more. And I didn't want to code anything. Maven plugin seemed better.

Comment: Have you provided the database driver in the property file ?.